# Force suds to use naive datetime

Tags: python, datetime, suds

I'm trying to consume a web service with suds, but came across an issue that hopefully someone here might be able to help me with.

Basically the problem is that the specific method we use requires us to pass a dateTime object to determine the date a service is to be stopped, the problem is that suds is forcing a -4 timezone (the correct time zone for the computer where the script is hosted) at the end of the resulting string, however, it seems our provider uses interprets this wrongly and causes the date to be off by a day early.

We have tried this web service before from php passing a naive "dateTime" object (basically a string like "YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss") and it works fine, which hints the timezone is what's causing the issue.

So I guess the real question is, how can I force suds to use a naive dateTime object OR to use a different timezone (I suspect the server is configured with a UTC timezone and this is what is causing the issue).

Thanks in advance for all your help

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with this. I edited the Lib\site-packages\suds\sax\date.py at line 297. I commented out self.__adjust() and it now does not adjust the time based on timezone.

```
    if isinstance(date, basestring):
        part = date.split('T')
        Date.__init__(self, part[0])
        Time.__init__(self, part[1], 0)
        self.datetime = \
            dt.datetime.combine(self.date, self.time)
        # self.__adjust()
        return
    raise ValueError, type(date)
```

I was getting "2013-04-16T23:00:00" and now I am getting the correct value of "2013-04-17T00:00:00".

Answer (score 0):

I realize this thread is quite ancient. However, you might want to check the following:
https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/353

Suds appears to be pretty brain dead in its handling of datetimes.